# Does the following set of polynomials non-negative on the interval $[0,1]^2$ positively span all non-negative polynomials on the interval?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, proof-writing, convex-geometry

Given the following set of polynomials that are non-negative on the interval $[0,1]^2$

$$
B = \{x, 1-x, y,1-y,xy,x-xy,y-xy,1-x-y+xy\} = \{b_1,b_2,...,b_8\}
$$

Can we definitively say that all polynomials with linear terms (I have no idea what the term is for this, I mean that there are no $x^2$ or $y^2$) that are non-negative on $[0,1]^2$ can be written as a linear combination of **non-negative** coefficients and these polynomials?

Or in math notation

Given $p(x,y)\mid p(x,y)\geq0 \forall(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$

Does there exist a $c_1,c_2,...,c_8\in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \mid c_1b_1+c_2b_2+ ... +c_8b_8=p(x,y)$

My gut instinct says **yes** because the 1-dimensional case is true:

Given $b=\{x, 1-x\} = \{b_1, b_2\}$, and $p(x)\in \mathbb{P}_1\mid p(x)\geq 0 \forall x\in[0,1]$

Prove $\exists c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq0} \mid c_1b_1 + c_2b_2 = p(x)$

*Proof*: Since $p(x)\in \mathbb{P}_2$, $p(x) = mx+a$. From the theorem, $p(x) = c_1b_1+c_2b_2 = c_1x+c_2(1-x) = (c_1-c_2)x+c_2$. Since $p(x)$ is non-negative at $p(0)$, $a\geq0$, and we can see that $a=c_2\therefore c_2\geq 0$. We apply the same process to see that $p(1) = m+a\geq0$. We also see that $m = c_1-c_2 \implies m+c_2 = c_1 \implies m+b = c_1 \therefore c_1\geq0$. This shows that we can write every polynomial as a positive combination of our basis **Q.E.D.**

Obviously this process is very tedious, and I wanted to see if there was an easier way to prove it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These polynomials have 4 degrees of freedom: their values in the four corners of the square. Each such polynomial $p$ can be written as
$$
p(x,y) = p(1,1)xy + p(1,0)x(1-y) + p(0,1)(1-x)y + p(0,0)(1-x)(1-y),
$$
which should help your case.

Comment: So generalizing out, say I was looking for polynomials that had $n$ potential terms or degrees of freedom, and say I had $m$ linearly independent polynomials with $m\geq n$, could I always use this method?

Comment: You might look into Bernstein polynomials, but there are examples of non-negative polynomials with negative coefficients in the Bernstein basis. I have no idea about the generalization you have in mind.

Comment: My generalization is specifically, say I have $n$ dimensions. The polynomials I want to look at are polynomials of terms $deg\leq 3$, for example: $x_1 + x_2x_3 + x_3x_4x_5 + x_1x_3x_5 + ... $, and my basis is one that is every combination of three variables 
$x_1,(1-x_1)..,x_n,(1-x_n), x_1 x_x_2, (1-x_1)x_2, ..., x_ix_j x_k, (1-x_i)x_j x_k$ Pretty similar except even for $n>3$, the degree of each term is at most $3$. I wanted to know if my basis could positively create each of these polynomials that are always greater than $1$. Hopefully that made sense